# mysql update is not updating

Tags: php, mysql, forms

this is the  
code

```
if (isset($_POST['edit']) and $_POST['edit'] == 'page')
{
 $upage= mysql_query("UPDATE `upages` SET
 upage_name='$page_name',
 upage_content='$page_content',
 upage_act='$page_act',
 upage_count='$page_count',
 upage_com='$page_com',
 upage_pos='$upage_pos'
 WHERE
 upage_id='$gpageid' ");
 if (isset($upage))
 {
   print_r ($_POST);
 }
}
```

print_r result is 
Array ( [page_name] => ss [page_content] => sss [page_pos] => 1 [page_act] => 2 [page_com] => 2 [page_count] => 0 [edit] => page [upage_id] => 4 )

Comment: off topic, but please note that PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions are obsolete and deprecated. You are recommended to switch to using the PDO library instead, which is more up-to-date.

Comment: use the mysqli extension instead

Comment: As for why you're getting an error, we can't tell: you haven't shown us what the error message is, nor do we know what values are in any of the variables that you're putting into the query (`$page_name`, `$page_count`, `$gpageid` etc etc etc). Those are the places you need to be looking to find the problem. Also try printing the full query string. That may make things obvious.

Comment: Are you sure, the if() get's reached? And debug your query with mysql_query("yourquery") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: r u getting any error, echo query and run it directly in phpmyadmin

Comment: Are you connected with any database???

Comment: if is getting reached , it's giving no errors , it's print the $_POST AS I TYPED ABOVE !!! ,

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia yes and there's anthor add query in the same page working fine

Comment: Sidenote: Use `&&` instead of `AND` - `&&` has precedence over `AND`

Comment: Is your `$gpageid` being set correctly?

Comment: i think i got the problem <br> when i try to update from phpmyadmin and use where id=12 for an ex, and hit go nothing happens but when i remove where id=num it's update all the database data so the problem in the id row or what?

Comment: If you do not give a where condition it will update all the rows of that table. Does that a `12` value exist under `upage_id`?

Comment: yes 12 is a value for a row <br> and i'm trying from phpmyadmin now , and it's updating all rows if i remove where id = whatever <br> whats the problem?

Comment: Can you paste your full update query here? Also create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) if possible.

Comment: There's a worryingly reckless disregard for [proper SQL escaping here](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use mysql_query('INSERT_QUERY') or die(mysql_error()); for fix debugging.

Comment: it's giving the same result

Comment: you are right, sorry! Use PMA or something else to debug your query.

Comment: i think i got the problem <br> when i try to update from phpmyadmin and use where id=12 for an ex, and hit go nothing happens but when i remove where id=num it's update all the database data so the problem in the id row or what?